# SQL Server Connection to Excel Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, sql

Upon re-opening my excel workbook, the SQL Server connection and associated queries are not saved and unable to be refreshed. How do I resolve this issue? I am accessing the DB via a remote connection and don't have access to a shared drive to create an ODBC connection.